# Applying a third condition to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following function which appliess css to #screen-nav when the user scrolls up and different css when user scrolls down

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var didScroll;
 var lastScrollTop = 0;
 var delta = 5;
 var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight(true);

$(window).scroll(function(event) { didScroll = true; });

 setInterval(function() {
   if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
   didScroll = false;
 }
 }, 0);

function hasScrolled() {
  if($( window ).width() > 768) {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
   return;
  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    // Scroll Down
        $('#screen-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
   } else { 
        $('#screen-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
   }  

 }
   lastScrollTop = st;
 }

});
```

css

```
 #screen-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

#screen-nav.nav-up { top: -100px; }
#screen-nav.nav-down { top: 0; }
```

I want to add a third class. I want  #screen-nav { top: 50px; } when the user is 300px from the top. (so I figure apply a third class .nav-top when the user is in that position) But not sure how to integrate it into my code.

Basically, I want the nav (navigation) to appear lower on the page when the user is at the top, and when it comes down when the user scrolls up, I want it to be right at the top.

Comment: You may want to check skrollr (not just for parallax):
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Comment: What are the conditions for the 3rd class? Just to be within 300px from the top of the document?

Comment: That's it! I just want the nav to be lower when the user is within 300px from the top. Everything I tried kept getting overridden or sometimes wouldn;t work when the user scrolled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add condition of javascript
if(st == 300){ $("#screen-nav").css({ top: '50px' }); }

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var didScroll;
     var lastScrollTop = 0;
     var delta = 5;
     var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight(true);

    $(window).scroll(function(event) { didScroll = true; });

     setInterval(function() {
       if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
       didScroll = false;
     }
     }, 0);

    function hasScrolled() {
      if($( window ).width() > 768) {
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
       return;

       if(st == 300)
       {
             $("#screen-nav").css({ top: '50px' });
       }
       else if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            // Scroll Down
            $('#screen-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
       }
       else { 
            $('#screen-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
       }  

     }
       lastScrollTop = st;
     }

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Won't the top:50px  be overruled by '.nav-down' since they could happen at the same time. As well, I probably didn't clarify correctly but I wanted it added if the user is 300px or less from the top .